# HTML5 input type to trigger facetime for mobile phone

Tags: html, facetime

Based on my research I haven't found a solution but a client wants to have their mobile site trigger Facetime on their user's phone (iPhone). I know skype works fine but for people on the go we would lke this functionality. Has anyone encountered this or have a clever work around?

This is what I am using:

```
<input type="tel" placeholder="xxx-xxx-xxxx" />
```

Thinking something like this: (use tel as a fallback..)

```
<input type="tel vidtel" placeholder="xxx-xxx-xxxx" />
```

Does this exist?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Apparently you can use a URL Scheme.

```
<a href="facetime:14085551234">Connect using FaceTime</a>
<a href="facetime:user@example.com">Connect using FaceTime</a>
```

Source:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/FacetimeLinks/FacetimeLinks.html

Comment: Same issue for me - but that solution isn't passing the address/number to be called to the app, it only opens it in iOS 8. Thoughts?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27749122/apple-facetime-url-scheme-not-initiating-call